# Como hacer una lista enlazada en Ruby

Tags: java, ruby

Tengo clase `Nodo` y la clase `Lista` para llamarlas desde `Main`; en *Java* lo he hecho pero no se como en *Ruby*.

En *Java* tendría lo que es:

```
class Nodo{

    String nombre, id, tel; Nodo enlace = null ;
}
```

con sus respectivos get y set.

Y clase `Lista` que tiene todos los métodos de *insertarporcabeza*, pero no sé cómo hacerlo en *Ruby*.

Ayuda.

**Clase Nodo**

```
public class Nodo {

int dato;
Nodo enlace;


/**
 * @return the dato
 */
 public int getDato() {
    return dato;
 }

/**
 * @param dato the dato to set
 */
 public void setDato(int dato) {
    this.dato = dato;
 }

/**
 * @return the enlace
 */
 public Nodo getEnlace() {
    return enlace;
 }

/**
 * @param enlace the enlace to set
 */
 public void setEnlace(Nodo enlace) {
    this.enlace = enlace;
 }

 public Nodo(int x){
    dato = x;
    enlace = null;
 }
 public Nodo(int x, Nodo n){ //el constructor en Java
    dato = x;
    enlace = null;
 }


}


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 public class Lista {
  private Nodo primero;

  public Lista(){
    primero = null;
 }

 public Lista insertarCabeceraLista(int entrada){
    Nodo nuevo;

    nuevo = new Nodo(entrada);
    nuevo.enlace=primero;
    primero = nuevo;

    return this;
 }

 public void visualizar(){
    Nodo n;
    int k = 0;

    n=primero;
    while(n != null){
        System.out.print(n.dato + " ");
        n = n.enlace;

        k++;

        System.out.print((k%10 != 0 ? " " : "\n"));
    }
 }
}
```

Ese sería todo mi codigo en Java, ahora necesito que alguien me ayude a que funcione en Ruby

Comment: podrías compartir el resto del código para ayudarte a traducirlo?

Comment: Hola, he puesto todo mi codigo de Java que funciona a la perfeccion. ahora no se como sería en Ruby

Comment: Tu código tiene algunos defectos, espero no te moleste corregirlos para obtener una mejor traducción, por ejemplo, no está bien encapsulado pues las variables son visibles fuera del objeto.

Comment: estabien, no hay problema, agradezco la ayuda que me aportan.

Comment: vale me avisas en cuanto lo tengas amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No difiere mucho del proceso en java, te paso un código sobre una clase ListaEnlazada y Nodo similares, que espero te sirvan de ayuda:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

# lista enlazada

class ListaEnlazada
  attr_accessor :primero, :ultimo # crea get set de primero y ultimo de la lista

  def initialize # define elemento vacio de lista enlazada
    @primero = @ultimo = nil
  end

  def insertarAlPrincipio(valor)
    nodo = Nodo.new(valor) # creamos nodo nuvo
    nodo.enlace= @primero  # unimos con el primero
    @primero = nodo  # ahora el primero es el nuevo
    @ultimo = nodo if @ultimo.nil? # y el último si era lista vacía

  end

  def insertarAlFinal(valor)
    nodo = Nodo.new(valor)

    @primero = nodo if @primero.nil?
    @ultimo.enlace = nodo unless @ultimo.nil?

    @ultimo = nodo
  end

  def verLista()
    temp = @primero
    while !( temp.nil?)
      print temp.dato.to_s + ' '
      temp = temp.enlace
    end
    puts " "
  end 
end

class Nodo
  attr_accessor :dato # crea get set de dato
  def initialize(valor) # define un nodo
    @dato = valor
    @enlace = nil # llamado sig (de siguiente) en otras nomenclaturas
  end

  def enlace # getEnlace de forma manual
    @enlace
  end

  def enlace=(valor) # setEnlace
    @enlace = valor
  end

end

list = ListaEnlazada.new()
list.insertarAlPrincipio(1)
list.insertarAlPrincipio(2)
list.insertarAlPrincipio(3)
list.insertarAlFinal(0)
list.verLista
# => 3 2 1 0  # salida esperada
```

De propina comento el proceso de insertar al principio y se uncluye método de insertr al final. Para esta lista e incluido elementos "primero" y "ultimo" en su especificación. Salud